# Unclear iCloud Photo Library Feature

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, ios

If I fill up the space on my iPhone with photos, but those photos are synced with iCloud Photo Library, how do I remove those photos from my iPhone without deleting them from iCloud Photo Library. Hence, when I try to delete a photo it says:

> This photo will be deleted from iCloud Photo Library on all your
>   devices.

Seems like I'm stuck?

Comment: I can't tell you for certain right now, but I think it doesn't delete it from your iCloud Photo Library. It only deletes it from your devices.

Comment: @Spotlight This is wrong. As the message indicates, deleting a photo from the iCloud photo library deletes it everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your goal is to free up space, you can configure your iPhone to only store thumbnails of the photos you have in iCloud Photo Library rather than the full-resolution images.

This is configured in **Settings > iCloud > Photos > Optimize iPhone Storage** (as opposed to *Download and Keep Originals*)

See this **[iMore article](http://www.imore.com/how-free-storage-space-your-iphone-or-ipad-icloud-photo-library)** for more information on optimising storage.

It is not currently possible to *completely* remove photos or videos from one device when using iCloud Photo Library. This is clarified in the **[iCloud Photo Library beta FAQ](http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT6378)**:

> Deleting a photo or video from your Photos app will also remove the
>   item from iCloud Photo Library and from your iCloud storage
>   allocation.

The solution would be to disable iCloud Photo Library, allowing you to delete certain photos from certain devices, but then new photos would not be synchronised automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already have this feature enabled. I have a huge photo library with many videos. Question still remains.

Comment: @VIPPY To the best of my knowledge there is no way to do this while using iCloud Photo Library. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you Lyes. This is a bummer as I was hoping to include my entire photo library (from my Mac) when the new Photos app becomes available in March. Golden wish: have a complete cloud solution that will allow me to access terabytes of photos/videos/documents from a phone or tablet that has minimal capacity. =)

Comment: I guess next question is, how optimized are these photos (and do the videos get optimized too). IE: a photo that is normally 3MB is optimized down to 500K.